# Net::Server incompatible with MongoDB

Tags: perl, mongodb

When I am running this code inside of a module that inherits from [Net::Server](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aServer), MongoDB doesn't seem to work:

```
use base qw(Net::Server);
```

When I call this code without that inheritance, it works fine.

```
Can't locate object method "run_command" via package "MongoDB::Database" at /usr/local/lib/perl5/MongoDB/Connection.pm line 519
MongoDB::Connection::_get_max_bson_size('MongoDB::Connection=HASH(0x9d48bc8)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/MongoDB/Connection.pm line 463
MongoDB::Connection::BUILD('MongoDB::Connection=HASH(0x9d48bc8)', 'HASH(0x9d48ba8)') called at /opt...
```

Here is the line that is failing:

```
$mongo_handle =
  MongoDB::Connection->new( 'host' => 'mongodb://' . $host . ':' . $port );
```

Comment: base.pm is problematic sometimes — can you try installing parent and changing `use base` to `use parent`, or else changing to `use Net::Server; BEGIN { unshift @ISA, "Net::Server" }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds similar to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PERL-78. Did you make sure you have the latest version of most libraries? It would help if you could state version of Perl, MongoDB Perl Driver, etc. that you use.

Comment: Perl: v5.10.1, MongoDB Perl module: 0.45.  I saw that post but I don't think anything I am running is ancient.

Comment: How about Any::Moose? Do you have it?